# Converting band interleaved by pixel binary files into raster grids

Tags: r, matrix, binary, raster

I have a BIP binary file `https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwkLXkUMkLd4SnBmUHNmMW5CcDg`
with the following information:

```
ncol <- 193 
nrow <- 94  
xmin <- -180
xmax<-  180
ymin <- -88.542000
ymax <- 88.542000
```

The file has 365 bands, I want to be able to convert them into raster grids (raster stack). 
I can read the files in R, but I don't know how to deal with the bands. Here is what I have done so far:

```
cnt <- ncol*nrow*365
data <- readBin(file,what= "double", n=cnt, size=4,endian=.Platform$endian)
data.m <- matrix(data, ncol=193, nrow=94) # I don't know how to add the bands
data.r <- raster(data.m, xmn=xmin, xmx=xmax, ymn=ymin, ymx=ymax)
plot(data.r)
```

Comment: Is there a way you can provide us with a few layers or a spot to obtain your data that isn't going through your drive?

Comment: unfortunately, that's the only example that I have.

Comment: Your example file is not publicly accessible

Comment: @LucasFortini I changed the settings. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use raster::brick as it is a function to create multi-band rasters based on files with multiple bands including BIL and BIP. 
If it by chance does not recognize your georef data, you can input it as arguments when reading the file: ncols=193, xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-88.542000, ymx=88.542000, nl=365.

Here is an example implementation based on the file you provided. Since it was not recognized as a BIP file, you first have to read it and convert it into an 3D array. Then you can simply use it with the brick command to create the raster stack. Now, the tricky thing is that the dimensions of the data file where in an order incompatible with the brick command, so you have to transpose the dimensions using the aperm function. After that, it is straight forward to convert the entire array into a georeferenced stack.

```
wd="D:/temp/"
setwd(wd)
library(raster)
ncol <- 193 
nrow <- 94  
nbands <- 365
cnt <- ncol*nrow*nbands
data <- readBin("Tavg.dat",what= "double", n=cnt, size=4,endian=.Platform$endian)
data2=array(data,c(nbands, ncol, nrow))
data2 <- aperm(data2, c(3,2,1)) #for transposing
raster_brick=brick(data2, xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-88.542000, ymx=88.542000)
plot(raster_brick[[1]])
```

Here is the first band image:
[image]

Comment: raster requires matrix data type, but here the data is numeric. Could you show it with codes?

Comment: Here is a working example. You will have to find out more about how the data was originally stored to properly build the array to create the raster brick, as mentioned above

Comment: Playing around with the dimensions of the array I found the exact working solution.

Comment: Interesting! what are the new dimensions?

Comment: The dimensions are the same, as you originally had, but as can be seen from the aperm function, the data was saved with the band values, then lon and lat, whereas brick tackes an array with lat, long, and band.

Comment: No problem. What is this data for, just for curiosity?

Comment: These are average daily temperatures. I got from someone.

Answer (score 2):

You can also write a header file. For example, rename 'Tavg.dat' to 'Tavg.gri' and save the below to a text file called 'Tavg.grd'

```
[georeference]
nrows=94
ncols=193
xmin=-180
ymin=-88.542
xmax=180
ymax=88.542
projection=+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
[data]
datatype=FLT4S
byteorder=little
nbands=365
bandorder=BIP
nodatavalue=-9999
[description]
layername=''
```

Then you can do

```
library(raster)
b <- brick('Tavg.grd')
```

Comment: This is great, Thanks!

Comment: I will use that for sure in the future!