# .dat to raster conversion

Tags: r, url-rewriting, raster

I have downloaded a [dataset](ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/pub/DATASETS/FREEZE-THAW-INDICES/) that is supposed to be a global map of freezing and thawing indices. Unfortunately I cannot uploaded or view it as a `raster` in R. Does anyone know how to convert this type of file to a .bil file?

I can load the file using: `dat<- read.delim('freez.dat', header = F)`
But I cannot get this to plot as a traditional raster.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Unless you know what the binary format is, you would be better taking the ascii file which is presumably "freez_a.dat"

Comment: Will that freez_a_.dat file load as a regular raster file or does it also need to be coverted?

Comment: you need to know some info about the binary file such is its dimension; see this link to read them using r raster library: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32910919/converting-band-interleaved-by-pixel-binary-files-into-raster-grids]

Comment: You will have to look at the format of freez_a.dat. But you can probably import it with read.table and then process as necessary

Comment: Look at the answer by RobertH in the link, its much easier using raster grid format.